# Cant unlink a curve created from an instanced collection

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, collections

Once I click on "Make Instances Real", It unlinks the geometry from the copy and it makes it unique.

Now for the curves, once I try to edit the new "real" curves, I am unnable to unlink them. I have created them from instancing a collection. I have tried everything from
1- Unparenting
2- Setting it to single user
3- Applying all the transforms
4- Tried to click on "unlink object data" but such option only exists for meshes.
Image 1. The right side of the curves is a copied collection made real
[image: Image 1. The right side of the curves is a copied collection made real]

Image 1. The right side of the curves is a copied collection made real
[image]

Image 2. The right side is selected in object mode

[image]

Image 3. In edit mode, the right side gets selected and all changes to the right side will affect the other one as well. I would like to make them individual of each other.

Any help or advice is welcome. I found that linking meshes to curves to be a great technique for applying hair cards and it is working really well for a ghillie camo outfit that I am creating for a game.

---

I have read this page from the manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html but it doesnt say anything about curves. The only thing that seemed to work in the sense of editing only one of the two sides was to press ctrl+L and click on link object data but that messed up the position and transform of my meshes. I tried to apply the transforms but to no avail. In other words, I have no solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Found this unanswered question as I was facing the exact same problem -- I solved it with this:

In Object Mode, select all objects that you want to be separated. When I "made instances real" I was able to select them individually in Object Mode, but they would all edit together in Edit Mode.

Use the Object dropdown menu > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data.
I did not unlink my textures, as I wanted them to remain uniform for the time being. This will make every selected object an individual editable object. This was enough for my own problem.

If you want to regroup objects -- perhaps all the objects on the right side -- Select them in Object Mode, Object dropdown > Relations > Make Local > Selected Objects and Data. This somehow relinks them, but not vertex to vertex as they were before. I haven't been able to find the solution to this second half of the problem.

For further clarification on what this is doing, look up "Make Single User" and "Data Blocks". I'd explain it here if I fully understood it myself.

Hope this helps some!